# How do I use the For loop in my code?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var string1 = "I am going to school.";
var string2 = "We need five different strings.";
var string3 = "Ace has to use the bathroom.";
var string4 = "Alex cant think of anything thing.";
var string5 = "Fingers are sometimes called digits.";

var string1word =(string1.substring(0,string1.search(" ")));

var string2word =(string2.substring(0,string2.search(" ")));

var string3word =(string3.substring(0,string3.search(" ")));

var string4word =(string4.substring(0,string4.search(" ")));

var string5word =(string5.substring(0,string5.search(" ")));


confirm(string1word+", " +", "+ string2word +", "+ string3word +", "+ string4word +", "+ string5word);
```

---

Hello, my assignment was to create a "program" that puts out the first words of any string. I have done this assignment but it is very repetitive. My teacher told me to use the for loop function to clean it up but I have no idea how to format or use the for loop here. I was wondering if some one could help me with using the for loop and to explain why/how it works here.

Comment: Have you learned arrays yet?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** The only reason I'm touching a homework question on StackOverflow is because it looks like you made a good attempt at completing the assignment on your own. Your code works as-is but you're looking for ways to improve it to meet additional criteria. This is respectable work ethic and I'm happy to help you in this case.

```
// create a reusable function
function firstWord(str) {
  return str.substring(0, str.search(" "));
}

// define strings
var string1 = "I am going to school.";
var string2 = "We need five different strings.";
var string3 = "Ace has to use the bathroom.";
var string4 = "Alex cant think of anything thing.";
var string5 = "Fingers are sometimes called digits.";

// put strings in an array
var strings = [string1, string2, string3, string4, string5];

// use a loop to iterate through the array
for (var i = 0, len = strings.length; i < len; i++) {

  // alert the firstWord of each string
  alert(firstWord(strings[i]));
}
```

Output

```
I
We
Ace
Alex
Fingers
```

---

You could also skip assigning `string1`, `string2`, ... `stringN` individually and just put them in the `strings` array directly

```
// define strings
var strings = [
  "I am going to school.",
  "We need five different strings.",
  "Ace has to use the bathroom.",
  "Alex cant think of anything thing.",
  "Fingers are sometimes called digits."
];

// for loop here ...
```

---

**Edit:** If you need the output in one long string as you have in your code, you could do something like this.

```
// create a reusable function
function firstWord(str) {
  return str.substring(0, str.search(" "));
}

// define strings
var strings = [
  "I am going to school.",
  "We need five different strings.",
  "Ace has to use the bathroom.",
  "Alex cant think of anything thing.",
  "Fingers are sometimes called digits."
];

// set savedWords array
var savedWords = [];

// use a loop to iterate through the array
for (var i = 0, len = strings.length; i < len; i++) {

  // store first word in savedWords array
  savedWords[i] = firstWord(strings[i]);
}

// output list of saved words separated by a comma
confirm(savedWords.join(", "));
```

Most of the code here is the same, but instead of calling `alert` on each word, we're saving the first word into a new `savedWords` array.

After we've found the first word of each string, we call [.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on `savedWords` to output the list of words as a single string.

---

**Advanced:** There's ways to make this even more concise, but your teacher may not permit the usage of higher level functions. Here's the shortest program I can write that meets the criteria for your program

```
// create a reusable function
function firstWord(str) {
  return str.substring(0, str.search(" "));
}

// define strings
var strings = [
  "I am going to school.",
  "We need five different strings.",
  "Ace has to use the bathroom.",
  "Alex cant think of anything thing.",
  "Fingers are sometimes called digits."
];

// output firstWord-mapped array of strings
confirm(strings.map(firstWord).join(", "));
```

This uses [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is a bit advanced for beginners. The basic idea is `.map` allows you to call a function for each item in an array and returns a fresh array with the results of each function call.

Here's another simple example that might help demonstrate how `.map` is working

```
// square a number function
function squareNumber(n) {
  return n * n;
}

// set some numbers
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

// get an array of the squares
var squares = numbers.map(squareNumber);

// output
confirm(squares.join(", "));
```

Output

```
1, 4, 9
```

---

**As a single expression:** for the naysayers that say "the code could be shorter", you could even write the entire program as a single expression

```
confirm([
  "I am going to school.",
  "We need five different strings.",
  "Ace has to use the bathroom.",
  "Alex cant think of anything thing.",
  "Fingers are sometimes called digits."
].map(function(s) { return s.substring(0, s.search(" ")); }).join(", "));

//=> I, We, Ace, Alex, Fingers
```

However, you sacrifice a lot of readability with this. I'm only showing you this example to demonstrate that JavaScript is quite expressive and allows you to chain things together in pretty neat ways.

Anyway, the lesson here is **don't** write code this way just because you can. Shorter code does not always mean  better.

Comment: what is the reason for that,what does it do?firstword?is that built into javascript,does it know what the first word is? does the i<s.length tell the program to run until the i is greater than the words. so since there it 5 first words it will run until it hits 5 then stop? i++ adds something to something.. I posted this to the other guy too but I would like some help with why some of these things work, and btw about my hw/project.It is a intro HS course and my teacher wants me to learn more about coding, anything I learn now will only help me in the future, be it through him or the internet

Answer (score 0):

Try This one, please

```
var s = [
  "I am going to school.",
  "We need five different strings.",
  "Ace has to use the bathroom.",
  "Alex cant think of anything thing.",
  "Fingers are sometimes called digits."
];

for (var i=0, firstWord; i<s.length; i++){
  firstword = s[i].substring(0,s[i].search(" "));
  confirm(firstword);
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the syntax formatting on your code. Considering you're trying to teach a beginner, you should be showing them best practices right away otherwise they'll pick up terrible habits.

Comment: はい、分かりました。ありがとうございます。(Yes, I have understood  your explanation. Thank you for your advice)

Comment: Wait, you have 4 statements. The first one does what? set i = 0? what is the reason for that, what does it do? firstword? is that built into javascript, does it know what the first word is? does the i<s.length tell the program to run until the i is greater than the words. so since there it 5 first words it will run until it hits 5 then stop? i++ adds something to something...

Comment: The first one i=0 means the first index(address)of array. The second one firstword is the variable to store the return value from substring function. The third one is i<s.length give the length of array. So, by using s.length, you can input additional any number of string. Thank You.